# libgdx game crash: "A L lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed" on Desktop and "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)" on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i've started programming with libgdx and i've made a platformer game, similar to mario. The problem comes when i run the game, it gets a crash.
On android the crash happens in less than half a minute and i get this error:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1000e in tid 10731 (GLThread 18415)
```

On pc the crash happens whenever, sometimes i can play the hole lvl without problems and sometimes it crash after a couple seconds. I get this error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=6980, tid=0x0000000000000b04

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
E:\Android Projects\oscarinabros2\android\assets\hs_err_pid6980.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

And creates a file on my assets folder:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=6980, tid=0x0000000000000b04
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000059886800):  JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=2820, stack(0x000000005acb0000,0x000000005adb0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000002000404040

Registers:
RAX=0x0000002000404040, RBX=0x00000000003af890, RCX=0x00000000003af860, RDX=0x00000000000000b8
RSP=0x000000005adaea10, RBP=0x0000000000000006, RSI=0x00000000003af860, RDI=0x000000005adaead0
R8 =0x00000000003af860, R9 =0x0000000000000002, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000001
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000056e395f0, R14=0x0000000000000010, R15=0x0000000059886800
RIP=0x0000000066bcbd0d, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000005adaea10)
0x000000005adaea10:   00000000003c8b00 000000000000016b
0x000000005adaea20:   00000000003f8f10 0000000066bc39ae
0x000000005adaea30:   00000000003af860 00000000003af860
0x000000005adaea40:   0000000000000001 000000005adaead0
0x000000005adaea50:   000000005adaebf0 0000000000000000
0x000000005adaea60:   0000000056e395f0 0000000066be2483
0x000000005adaea70:   00000000000005d0 0000000066be0498
0x000000005adaea80:   0000000000000009 0000000059886800
0x000000005adaea90:   0000000000000001 0000000000000001
0x000000005adaeaa0:   0000000000000001 0000000066be8616
0x000000005adaeab0:   0000000000000088 00000000000000fa
0x000000005adaeac0:   0000000000000780 00000000003f3788
0x000000005adaead0:   4296c7ae00000002 000000003eb33333
0x000000005adaeae0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005adaeaf0:   0000010100000000 00000000d5f9ad01
0x000000005adaeb00:   0000000000000000 000000003f800000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d)
0x0000000066bcbced:   48 8d 05 6c a3 05 00 0f b6 1c 18 80 fb 0d 0f b6
0x0000000066bcbcfd:   eb 77 21 48 8d 1c de 48 8b 43 10 48 85 c0 74 3a
0x0000000066bcbd0d:   48 8b 10 48 89 53 10 48 83 c4 28 5b 5e 5f 5d 41
0x0000000066bcbd1d:   5c 41 5d c3 48 8d 15 18 9e 04 00 48 8d 0d 99 9e 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000002000404040 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000003af890 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000003af860 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000000000000b8 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000005adaea10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000059886800
RBP=0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000003af860 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000005adaead0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000059886800
R8 =0x00000000003af860 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000056e395f0 is pointing into metadata
R14=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000059886800 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000005acb0000,0x000000005adb0000],  sp=0x000000005adaea10,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x22483]
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x28616]
C  0x000000000255df24

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 626  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniCreateBody(JIFFFFFFFFZZZZZF)J (0 bytes) @ 0x000000000255dea6 [0x000000000255de00+0xa6]
J 625 C1 com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.createBody(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body; (120 bytes) @ 0x000000000255d3fc [0x000000000255d260+0x19c]
J 1215 C1 tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.sprites.enemies.Bala.defineEnemy()V (105 bytes) @ 0x00000000026feb04 [0x00000000026fe760+0x3a4]
J 1351 C2 tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.sprites.enemies.David.update(F)V (170 bytes) @ 0x000000000278c240 [0x000000000278b8c0+0x980]
J 1235 C1 tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.screens.PlayScreen.update(F)V (315 bytes) @ 0x0000000002715d1c [0x0000000002715400+0x91c]
J 1355 C1 tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.screens.PlayScreen.render(F)V (418 bytes) @ 0x00000000027a3e2c [0x00000000027a3da0+0x8c]
J 1320 C1 tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.OscarinaBros.render()V (5 bytes) @ 0x000000000276442c [0x0000000002764220+0x20c]
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop()V+698
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run()V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000059afe000 JavaThread "LWJGL Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4772, stack(0x000000005bca0000,0x000000005bda0000)]
  0x0000000001db8000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3900, stack(0x0000000001ec0000,0x0000000001fc0000)]
=>0x0000000059886800 JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=2820, stack(0x000000005acb0000,0x000000005adb0000)]
  0x0000000058c20000 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3764, stack(0x0000000059470000,0x0000000059570000)]
  0x0000000058a71000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4808, stack(0x0000000058e30000,0x0000000058f30000)]
  0x0000000058a05800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5996, stack(0x0000000058fd0000,0x00000000590d0000)]
  0x0000000058a00800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5032, stack(0x0000000058800000,0x0000000058900000)]
  0x0000000057098800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6500, stack(0x0000000058900000,0x0000000058a00000)]
  0x0000000057094000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2484, stack(0x0000000058690000,0x0000000058790000)]
  0x0000000057092800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5072, stack(0x00000000584e0000,0x00000000585e0000)]
  0x000000005707b000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6552, stack(0x0000000057fe0000,0x00000000580e0000)]
  0x0000000057034000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3856, stack(0x0000000058340000,0x0000000058440000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000005702c800 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000580e0000,0x00000000581e0000] [id=2200]
  0x0000000058a8a800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000059250000,0x0000000059350000] [id=7016]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 9645K [0x00000000d5d00000, 0x00000000d8780000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 15% used [0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d621b6c8,0x00000000d7d80000)
  from space 5120K, 86% used [0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d81cff70,0x00000000d8280000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8780000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 80K [0x0000000081600000, 0x0000000086b80000, 0x00000000d5d00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081600000,0x0000000081614010,0x0000000086b80000)
 Metaspace       used 8927K, capacity 9055K, committed 9344K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 843K, capacity 852K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011650000,0x0000000011a50000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011245000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006e7fa6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012350000, 0x00000000142f8000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000142f8000, 0x00000000162a0000)

Polling page: 0x00000000001c0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=5222Kb max_used=5229Kb free=240537Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002290000, 0x00000000027c0000, 0x0000000011290000]
 total_blobs=1865 nmethods=1357 adapters=421
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 100.915 Thread 0x0000000058a05800 1363       3       com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Value$3::get (30 bytes)
Event: 100.916 Thread 0x0000000058a05800 nmethod 1363 0x0000000002789d90 code [0x0000000002789f20, 0x000000000278a4c8]
Event: 100.916 Thread 0x0000000058a05800 1365       3       com.badlogic.gdx.utils.FloatArray::get (54 bytes)
Event: 100.917 Thread 0x0000000058a05800 nmethod 1365 0x0000000002790550 code [0x0000000002790760, 0x00000000027911d8]
Event: 100.917 Thread 0x0000000058a05800 1364       3       com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Value$4::get (30 bytes)
Event: 100.918 Thread 0x0000000058a05800 nmethod 1364 0x0000000002789450 code [0x00000000027895e0, 0x0000000002789b88]
Event: 104.197 Thread 0x0000000057098800 1366       4       org.lwjgl.opengl.Display::getHeight (30 bytes)
Event: 104.200 Thread 0x0000000057098800 nmethod 1366 0x00000000027b0790 code [0x00000000027b08e0, 0x00000000027b0b38]
Event: 105.147 Thread 0x0000000058a00800 1367       4       com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera::update (164 bytes)
Event: 105.176 Thread 0x0000000058a00800 nmethod 1367 0x00000000027adc90 code [0x00000000027adee0, 0x00000000027ae890]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 87.103 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 33280K [0x00000000d5d00000, 0x00000000d8780000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d7d80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8780000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d8280000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081600000, 0x0000000086b80000, 0x00000000d5d00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081600000,0x0000000081600000,0x0000000086b80000)
 Metaspace       used 8885K, capacity 8991K, committed 9088K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 843K, capacity 852K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 87.111 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 4415K [0x00000000d5d00000, 0x00000000d8780000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 0% used [0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d7d80000)
  from space 5120K, 86% used [0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d81cff70,0x00000000d8280000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8780000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 80K [0x0000000081600000, 0x0000000086b80000, 0x00000000d5d00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081600000,0x0000000081614010,0x0000000086b80000)
 Metaspace       used 8885K, capacity 8991K, committed 9088K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 843K, capacity 852K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 86.499 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000267b33c method=com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 46
Event: 86.499 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000267b33c method=com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 46
Event: 86.499 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000267b33c method=com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 46
Event: 86.514 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000026f04c8 method=com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.WidgetGroup.validate()V @ 75
Event: 87.118 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000267b33c method=com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 46
Event: 87.230 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002675834 method=tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.sprites.enemies.David.update(F)V @ 99
Event: 87.230 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000026e91e8 method=com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.WidgetGroup.validate()V @ 75
Event: 91.897 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002643278 method=tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.sprites.enemies.Snake.update(F)V @ 14
Event: 91.898 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002647184 method=tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.sprites.enemies.Snake.draw(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch;)V @ 4
Event: 97.930 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000279763c method=tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.screens.PlayScreen.handleInput(F)V @ 124

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.127 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d60af390) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.127 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d60b3460) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.127 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d60b3670) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61efe28) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61f1b00) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61f2c70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61f7dd8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61f8a30) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x0000000001db8000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61f9658) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 87.230 Thread 0x0000000059886800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000026746e9 to 0x0000000002675829

Events (10 events):
Event: 97.930 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x000000000279763c sp=0x000000005adaefc0
Event: 97.930 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000022d582a sp=0x000000005adaef38 mode 2
Event: 99.247 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000027174fd sp=0x000000005adaee10
Event: 99.247 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000022d787f sp=0x000000005adaebd0 mode 0
Event: 100.914 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000027174fd sp=0x000000005adaee10
Event: 100.914 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000022d787f sp=0x000000005adaebd0 mode 0
Event: 102.580 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000027174fd sp=0x000000005adaee10
Event: 102.580 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000022d787f sp=0x000000005adaebd0 mode 0
Event: 104.247 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000027174fd sp=0x000000005adaee10
Event: 104.247 Thread 0x0000000059886800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000022d787f sp=0x000000005adaebd0 mode 0


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f210000 - 0x000000013f247000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe
0x0000000076e80000 - 0x000000007702a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076c60000 - 0x0000000076d7f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefcea0000 - 0x000007fefcf0a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefede0000 - 0x000007fefeebb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefd070000 - 0x000007fefd10f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefeab0000 - 0x000007fefeacf000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefebb0000 - 0x000007fefecdd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076d80000 - 0x0000000076e7a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefcf70000 - 0x000007fefcfd7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefcfe0000 - 0x000007fefcfee000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefece0000 - 0x000007fefedaa000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefad50000 - 0x000007fefaf44000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefcff0000 - 0x000007fefd061000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefedb0000 - 0x000007fefedde000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefd600000 - 0x000007fefd709000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000070760000 - 0x0000000070832000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006dfe0000 - 0x000000006e87a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007feef9d0000 - 0x000007feef9d9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefd110000 - 0x000007fefd15d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefd3e0000 - 0x000007fefd3e8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef9ed0000 - 0x000007fef9f0b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefbe10000 - 0x000007fefbe1c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077040000 - 0x0000000077047000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000071660000 - 0x000000007166f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000071630000 - 0x0000000071659000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00000000709a0000 - 0x00000000709b6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefdd20000 - 0x000007fefeaaa000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefd3f0000 - 0x000007fefd5f3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefcbb0000 - 0x000007fefcbbf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefb950000 - 0x000007fefb95f000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x0000000070720000 - 0x000000007073a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefc390000 - 0x000007fefc3e5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc380000 - 0x000007fefc387000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x0000000065580000 - 0x0000000065616000     C:\Users\dam224\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxdam224\8aad67a5\gdx64.dll
0x000007fefc3f0000 - 0x000007fefc408000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc0f0000 - 0x000007fefc137000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcf40000 - 0x000007fefcf5e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefca50000 - 0x000007fefca5f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefbcf0000 - 0x000007fefbd17000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefbce0000 - 0x000007fefbceb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefa980000 - 0x000007fefa991000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fefa960000 - 0x000007fefa978000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x0000000070740000 - 0x0000000070751000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180053000     C:\Users\dam224\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxdam224\dc0f0009\lwjgl64.dll
0x000007fef3100000 - 0x000007fef321d000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x000007fef1c00000 - 0x000007fef1c2d000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x000007fef1b00000 - 0x000007fef1bf1000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x000007fef30f0000 - 0x000007fef30f8000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000007fefd200000 - 0x000007fefd3d7000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefcbd0000 - 0x000007fefcc06000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007fefead0000 - 0x000007fefebaa000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefcf20000 - 0x000007fefcf3a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fefa7a0000 - 0x000007fefa7b8000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x00000000121b0000 - 0x0000000012214000     C:\Users\dam224\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxdam224\dc0f0009\OpenAL64.dll
0x000007fefacf0000 - 0x000007fefad46000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007fefd8a0000 - 0x000007fefd939000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007fefa9a0000 - 0x000007fefaacc000     C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
0x000007fefcdb0000 - 0x000007fefcdeb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x000007fefcc40000 - 0x000007fefcdad000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefcbc0000 - 0x000007fefcbcf000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fef9660000 - 0x000007fef96e8000     C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll
0x000007fefb960000 - 0x000007fefb98c000     C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll
0x000007fefb0b0000 - 0x000007fefb0fb000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x000007fef9c70000 - 0x000007fef9cbf000     C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x000000005adb0000 - 0x000000005b556000     C:\Windows\system32\ig75icd64.dll
0x000007fef4160000 - 0x000007fef45aa000     C:\Windows\system32\igdusc64.dll
0x000007feef010000 - 0x000007feef0ac000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x000007fef9570000 - 0x000007fef95b2000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x0000000066bc0000 - 0x0000000066c7b000     C:\Users\dam224\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxdam224\b6038e5c\gdx-box2d64.dll
0x000007fef9b00000 - 0x000007fef9c25000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain tk.droptheswag.oscarinabros.desktop.DesktopLauncher
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\Android Projects\oscarinabros2\desktop\build\classes\main;E:\Android Projects\oscarinabros2\core\build\classes\main;C:\Users\dam224\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx\1.9.4\4b4b7962d1bc75af0438f5c81ec1010557bc9ee5\gdx-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\dam224\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d\1.9.4\98a0d25c9f0637fecac6e4aacf7287aa635964f5\gdx-box2d-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\dam224\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-backend-lwjgl\1.9.4\4c6c108a9dcbc07096de8594b93f9cab33856fe2\gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\dam224\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Norman\npm\bin;C:\Users\dam224\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\dam224\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\dam224\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2
USERNAME=dam224
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23539)

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, lzcnt, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 8292724k(3691020k free), swap 16583588k(10849440k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_101-b13), built on Jun 22 2016 01:21:29 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu Oct 06 09:30:17 2016
elapsed time: 107 seconds (0d 0h 1m 47s)
```

i've tried and searched but i cant find anything to solve it, any idea what could be the problem or how could i identify it? it doesnt seem to happen in any specific time or event.

Comment: Update the driver of your video card. Worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the error, i was trying to set active bodies from the b2world that were already destroyed, just added a condition so it doesnt do that if it is destroyed

```
for (Enemy enemy : creator.getEnemies()) {
                enemy.update(dt);
                if (!enemy.destroyed && enemy.getX() < player.getX() + 272 / OscarinaBros.PPM) {
                    enemy.b2body.setActive(true);
                }
            }
            for (Item item : creator.getItems()) {
                item.update(dt);
                if (!item.destroyed && item.getX() < player.getX() + 272 / OscarinaBros.PPM) {
                    item.b2body.setActive(true);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a crash in one of the (probably c) libraries used. EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION means you are trying to read/write memory that is not supposed to be read/written.

Something like (pseudo)

```
Array array = new Array[10]();
array[11] = 1;
```

What is going wrong is hard to say from this info. But these kind of unpredictable errors are usually a concurrency problem.